# convert jquery inArray to extjs equivalent

Tags: jquery, extjs

does extjs contain method equivalent to inArray? i checked the API but found nothing!

here is the jquery snippet that need urgent conversion:

```
if ($.inArray(checkbox.inputValue, values) >= 0)
```

where values is array.

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ext JS has [Array.indexOf](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Array), which does exactly the same thing that the unfortunately-named jQuery.inArray does:

```
if(values.indexOf(yourValue) !== -1)
```

Comment: Note that this is Ext 3 specific -- in Ext 4 the Array prototype is no longer modified, so you'd use Ext.Array.indexOf instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ext.js does not appear to have this function. See http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/

You can monkey patch this in if you like:

```
Ext.inArray = function(value, collection) {
    return collection.indexOf(value) !== -1;
};
```

Comment: To clarify, Ext *Core* does not have it, but Ext JS (the standard library) does support it, as shown in other answers. Also, I believe jQuery.inArray, like Array.indexOf, returns the matching index or -1, not a boolean like this example code (though the name would certainly imply it's a boolean, unfortunately).

Answer (score 2):

ExtJS 4 has [Array.contains](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-contains) method:

```
Ext.Array.contains(MyArray, MyString); // returns bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Ext.Array.indexOf` method:

```
Ext.Array.indexOf( Array array, Object item, [Number from] ) : Number
```

[documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-indexOf)

The resulting code would look like this:

```
if (Ext.Array.indexOf(checkbox.inputValue, values) >= 0)
```